# Will jQuery support OOP concepts?

Tags: jquery, html, oop

I am using this code in jquery to create a class and to make use of class variables anyone can help me how to do this when i am running this nothing is displaying on browser. And the class name should be generic.

and i want to build generic class for the simple arithmetic operations....

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var simpleClass = {

        testAttribute : "test", // atttribute

        testMethod : function() //method
        { 
            return testAttribute; } 

    };
    var simpleClassObj = new simpleClass();
    simpleClassObj.testAttriute;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
simpleClassObj.testAttriute;
```

does nothing because you are just writing the name of the attribute, without assigning it to a variable or echoing it to the screen or the console.

Also, you should look for any tutorial on JS classes, because that's not how you declare a class in JS. It should look something like this:

```
var simpleClass = function() {

    this.testAttribute = "test"; // atttribute

    this.testMethod = function() //method
    {
        return this.testAttribute;
    };

 };

var simpleClassObj = new simpleClass();
alert(simpleClassObj.testMethod());
```